# window.scrollTo not scrolling with overflow-y: scroll;

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jQuery snippet that scrolls to the next element. for some reason it doesn’t scroll when i have a div class of overflow-y: scroll;
Below is my complete code:

```js
var lstEl = null;
var cntr = -1;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnSearch').click(function() {
    lstEl = null;
    cntr = -1;
    var vl = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value;
    $("#bodyContainer").removeHighlight();
    $("#bodyContainer").highlight(vl);
  });

  $('#btnNext').click(function() {
    alert(cntr);
    if (lstEl === null) {
      lstEl = $('#bodyContainer').find('span.highlight');
      if (!lstEl || lstEl.length === 0) {
        lstEl = null;
        return;
      }
    }
    if (cntr < lstEl.length - 1) {
      cntr++;
      if (cntr > 0) {
        $(lstEl[0]).removeClass('current');
      }
      var elm = lstEl[cntr];
      $(elm).addClass('current');
    } else
      alert("End of search reached!");
  });

  $('#btnPrev').click(function() {
    alert(cntr);
    if (lstEl === null) {
      lstEl = $('#bodyContainer').find('span.highlight');
      if (!lstEl || lstEl.length === 0) {
        lstEl = null;
        return;
      }
    }
    if (cntr > 0) {
      cntr--;
      if (cntr < lstEl.length) {
        $(lstEl[cntr + 1]).removeClass('current');
      }
      var elm = lstEl[cntr];
      $(elm).addClass('current');
    } else
      alert("Begining of search!");
  });
});

$(function() {

  // the input field
  var $input = $("input[type='search']"),
    // clear button
    $clearBtn = $("button[data-search='clear']"),
    // prev button
    $prevBtn = $("button[data-search='prev']"),
    // next button
    $nextBtn = $("button[data-search='next']"),
    // the context where to search
    $content = $(".content"),
    // jQuery object to save <mark> elements
    $results,
    // the class that will be appended to the current
    // focused element
    currentClass = "current",
    // top offset for the jump (the search bar)
    offsetTop = 50,
    // the current index of the focused element
    currentIndex = 0;

  /**
   * Jumps to the element matching the currentIndex
   */
  function jumpTo() {
    if ($results.length) {
      var position,
        $current = $results.eq(currentIndex);
      $results.removeClass(currentClass);
      if ($current.length) {
        $current.addClass(currentClass);
        position = $current.offset().top - offsetTop;
        window.scrollTo(0, position);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Jumps to the element matching the currentIndex
   */
  function jumpTo() {
    if ($results.length) {
      var position,
        $current = $results.eq(currentIndex);
      $results.removeClass(currentClass);
      if ($current.length) {
        $current.addClass(currentClass);
        position = $current.offset().top - offsetTop;
        window.scrollTo(0, position);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Searches for the entered keyword in the
   * specified context on input
   */
  $input.on("input", function() {
    var searchVal = this.value;
    $content.unmark({
      done: function(totalMatches) {
        $content.mark(searchVal, {
          separateWordSearch: false,
          acrossElements: true,
          done: function(totalMatches) {
            $results = $content.find("mark");
            currentIndex = 0;
            jumpTo();
            var tag = field.find('[data-tag="' + keyword.toLowerCase() + '"]'),
              html = keyword;
            tag.addClass('active');
            if (totalMatches) {
              html += '<span class="kwt-count">' + totalMatches + '</span>';
            }
            tag.find('content').html(html);

          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

  /**
   * Clears the search
   */
  $clearBtn.on("click", function() {
    $content.unmark();
    $input.val("").focus();
  });

  /**
   * Next and previous search jump to
   */
  $nextBtn.add($prevBtn).on("click", function() {
    if ($results.length) {
      currentIndex += $(this).is($prevBtn) ? -1 : 1;
      if (currentIndex < 0) {
        currentIndex = $results.length - 1;
      }
      if (currentIndex > $results.length - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
      }
      jumpTo();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  Search:
  <input type="search" placeholder="Lorem">
  <button data-search="next">&darr;</button>
  <button data-search="prev">&uarr;</button>
  <button data-search="clear">✖</button>
  <span class="kwt-count"> matches</span>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis eu ullamcorper orci, eget p</p>
</div>
```

If i remove the overflow-y: scroll; it works just fine, but I need the overflow-y: scroll; to be in the css. I am not sure why it’s not scrolling.

Comment: Hi John. Please include a representation of your HTML that allows us to recreate the issue. Questions without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) are considered off-topic.

Comment: Hey Tyler I went ahead and added the complete html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about jQuery but I faced the same issue with vanilla JS's scrollIntoView method.

```
const scrollIntoView = id => {
  const element = document.querySelector(id);
  if (element) {
    element.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'nearest',
    });
  }
};
```

By using `block: 'nearest'` it scrolled relative to the nearest scrollable parent

Comment: Also try to use element.scrollIntoView it works better than window.scrollTo

Comment: get the dom node ref for the element.

Comment: I’m having a difficult time with this :(

Comment: figured it out!